# Use of @Value gives UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring

I have a class ApiRest which has a member named `myKey` which I am trying to set from value I get from an `abc.properties` file. When I use `@Value` to set the variable, I get the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name ...
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;

But if I set the value directly with `private String myKey = "my-Key";`, it works properly. My code looks like this:

```
@Path("api/data")
@Controller
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ApiRest{
    @Value("${my-service.key}")
    private String myKey;

    private final MyClient myClient = MyClient.builder().key(myKey).build();

    //Remaining Code
    //I use myClient Object to use one of its method
}
```

Why is `@Value` not able to inject the value in the variable and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please show your constructor. From the exception in looks like there is some problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read the value of a field that gets its value injected by a spring bean post processor before it actually gets injected.

See java doc of `@Value`

> Note that actual processing of the @Value annotation is performed by a
>   BeanPostProcessor

This means you are trying to read the value of the field `myKey` too early here:

```
private final MyClient myClient = MyClient.builder().key(myKey).build();
```

You should move the initialization of the field `myClient` to another method that is itself e.g. annotated with `@PostConstruct`

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.myClient = MyClient.builder().key(myKey).build();
}
```

Further reading can be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257237/how-to-use-spring-value-annotation-in-class-level-variables)